# How do I stop continuous loop of KEYDOWN?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame. Whenever I press the key "Delete". It prints "key" continuously. I only want it to print it only one time. How can I do this ?

```
import pygame

import sys
 

sprite = "sprite_1.jpg"

position = (20,0)
canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((952, 592))

color = (255,255,255)
exit = False 



back = pygame.image.load("th.jpg").convert_alpha()
back = pygame.transform.scale(back, (952,592))




Sprite = pygame.image.load(sprite)
Sprite.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

Sprite = pygame.transform.scale(Sprite, (35,35))


pygame.display.set_caption("Game")





while not exit:
    canvas.fill(color)
    canvas.blit(back, dest = (0,0))
    canvas.blit(Sprite, dest=position)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
            
    if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
        if (event.key == pygame.K_DELETE):
            print("hi")

    pygame.display.update()
```

Please tell the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: `update()` method runs once per frame, i.e. 30 times per second in PyGame, I think. If you want to print "hi" only once either check the status of Delete key once every 30 frames or create a counter that if it's happened before and less than 30 frames passed then it will continue to the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The event has to be handled in the event loop instead of the applicaition loop:

```py
while not exit:
    canvas.fill(color)
    canvas.blit(back, dest = (0,0))
    canvas.blit(Sprite, dest=position)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
    
    # INDENTATION  
    #-->|      
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_DELETE):
                print("hi")

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

count=0
while not exit:

```
enter code herecanvas.fill(color)
canvas.blit(back, dest = (0,0))
canvas.blit(Sprite, dest=position)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        exit = True
        
    if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
        if count<=0:         
            if (event.key == pygame.K_DELETE):
                print("hi")
        else:
            continue

pygame.display.update()
```